# How can I make an element's background transparent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I cant make the background of some elements transparent for mobile view. I'm using React.

I tried to add `background-color` and `background` with value `transparent` to nearly every class, but it does not remove the background properly. Does anyone have suggestions how to fix this?

standard view:
[image]

mobile view:
[image]

js:

```
export const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="flex custom-nav">
      <ul className="nav-list flex">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
      <span className="social-icon-list">
          <a href="#"><img className="social-icon" src={socialIcon1} 
          alt=""/></a>
          <a href="#"><img className="social-icon" src={socialIcon2} 
           alt=""/></a>
        </span>
      <button>Let's Connect</button>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

css for my js file

```
* {
    font-family: Centra, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1.5rem;
}

nav {
    padding: 20px 50px 0 0;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 18px 34px;
    font-size: 1.3em !important;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

.social-icon-list {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.social-icon {
    width: 42px;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    margin-right: 6px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

@media (max-width: 44em) {
    .custom-nav {
        position: fixed;
        inset: 0 0 0 30%;
        background: aqua;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: start;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .nav-list {
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: min(25vh, 5rem) 0 0 0;
        margin: 0;
        gap: 1rem;
    }

    button {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

css for the whole app

```
* {
    background-color: #262626;
}
```

Comment: This is a good example of the power and danger of `*`. I almost never use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in here:

```
* {
    background-color: #262626;
}
```

This sets the background color of absolutely ***everything***, so you'd have to overwrite it for absolutely *everything*.

If you want a "global" background, only set that on your root element. Generally, `html` or `body` are excellent containers for that:

```
body {
    background-color: #262626;
}
```